# SQL - how to find correlating rows? i.e. if a row with X value exists, is there another row with Y value?

Tags: sql, case

In SQL, I have a table of punch cards, showing who has clocked in for their respective shift that day, and who has clocked out of their shift for that day. Everyone who clocked in is expected to clock out, but we are having a problem where people clock in but forget to clock back out. I want to write a query that checks if anyone who clocked in did not clock out, and returns a list of who all forgot to clock out, and the last one they punched. I don't want to make a table keeping track of who's supposed to be clocking in and out, because someone may miss a day, or take a vacation day, etc.- but they all know to clock in, so I figure I can base my check off of that. Some example data is as follows:

```
DECLARE @PunchCards TABLE
(
    [Name] VARCHAR(20),
    [Shift] VARCHAR(30)
);
--John & Kate have clocked in & out properly, Doug forgot to clock out
INSERT INTO @PunchCards
    (Name, Shift)
VALUES
    ('John',           -- Name - varchar(20)
     'Start Day Shift' -- Shift - varchar(30)
    ),
    ('Doug',           -- Name - varchar(20)
     'Start Day Shift' -- Shift - varchar(30)
    ),
    ('John',         -- Name - varchar(20)
     'End Day Shift' -- Shift - varchar(30)
    ),
    ('Kate',             -- Name - varchar(20)
     'Start Night Shift' -- Shift - varchar(30)
    ),
    ('Kate',           -- Name - varchar(20)
     'End Night Shift' -- Shift - varchar(30)
    )
```

Based on that data, my query ought to return one row- Name = Doug, Shift = Start Day Shift.

I am stumped as to how to go about this- my working idea is to use a CASE WHEN and do a subquery within the case statement, to compare my current SELECT to the subquery, to see that if my current shift is 'Start Day Shift' or 'Start Night Shift', to make sure that whichever one it is, that it has its respective 'End Day Shift' or 'End Night Shift'. Even then that has my head spinning for how to break down this problem enough to tackle it. Any ideas for how I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: How are you going to keep the order?  Do you have a date/time stamp in PunchCards table?

Comment: This is a classic use case for exists and not exists clauses in sql

Comment: Does PunchCards only have one days worth of data at any point? The earlier comment is correct, how would you differentiate a clock in and out on Tuesday but only a clock in on Wednesday without a time field?

Comment: Yes, I've got a date column in my actual table, and my actual SQL job pulls back the last day's worth- I just wanted to keep the hypothetical question as simple as possible to boil it down to the base part I'm asking about.

Comment: @nawomack In that case Andomar's answer looks good. Only problem would be if people could clock in & out multiple times per day. Like they need to leave for a Dr's appointment and clock out, clock back in when they return and forget to clock out. That answer wouldn't return that person because it found a clock out occurrence. What you are really interested in is whether the last activity on a given day is a clock out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `not exists` clause that says there is no end shift:

```
select  Name
from    @PunchCards pc1
where   shift like 'Start % Shift'
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    @PunchCards pc2
        on      pc1.name = pc2.name
                and pc2.shift = replace(pc1.shift, 'Start', 'End')
        )
```

Comment: First time using 'NOT EXISTS', thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat strange task without unambiguous ordering of rows, but it is curious

```
select *
  ,case 
     when dir='1-Start' 
      and lead(dir,1,'-')over(partition by [name],DN order by rn)<>'2-End' 
         then 'no end'
     when dir='2-End' 
      and lag(dir,1,'-')over(partition by [name],DN order by rn)<>'1-Start' 
         then 'no Start'
   else ''
   end fl
From(
select *
  ,row_number()over(partition by [name],dn,dir order by dir)rn
from(
select *
  ,case when substring([Shift],1,9)='Start Day' or substring([Shift],1,7)='End Day' 
              then 'Day'
        when substring([Shift],1,11)='Start Night' or substring([Shift],1,9)='End Night'
              then 'Night'
   end DN
  ,case when left([Shift],5)='Start' then '1-Start'
        when left([Shift],3)='End' then '2-End'
   end dir
from PunchCards
) x
)y
order by name,dn,rn
```

For test data:

```
create table PunchCards([Name] VARCHAR(20),[Shift] VARCHAR(30));
--John & Kate have clocked in & out properly, Doug forgot to clock out
INSERT INTO PunchCards (Name, Shift)
VALUES
    ('John','Start Day Shift'),
    ('Doug','Start Day Shift'),
    ('John','End Day Shift'),
    ('Kate','Start Night Shift'),
    ('Kate','End Night Shift'),
    ('Paul','Start Day Shift'), 
    ('Paul','End Night Shift'), -- no Start Night
    ('Michael','End Day Shift'),   -- Ok
    ('Michael','Start Day Shift'), -- Ok
    ('Paul','Start Day Shift'), -- no End Day ,next row is used previous
    ('Paul','End Day Shift'), 
    ('Kate','End Night Shift')  -- no Start Night
;
```

result is

| Name | Shift | DN | dir | rn | fl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doug | Start Day Shift | Day | 1-Start | 1 | no end |
| John | Start Day Shift | Day | 1-Start | 1 |  |
| John | End Day Shift | Day | 2-End | 1 |  |
| Kate | Start Night Shift | Night | 1-Start | 1 |  |
| Kate | End Night Shift | Night | 2-End | 1 |  |
| Kate | End Night Shift | Night | 2-End | 2 | no Start |
| Michael | Start Day Shift | Day | 1-Start | 1 |  |
| Michael | End Day Shift | Day | 2-End | 1 |  |
| Paul | Start Day Shift | Day | 1-Start | 1 |  |
| Paul | End Day Shift | Day | 2-End | 1 |  |
| Paul | Start Day Shift | Day | 1-Start | 2 | no end |
| Paul | End Night Shift | Night | 2-End | 1 | no Start |

More simple, without parsing

```
with cte as(
select * 
  ,row_number()over(partition by [Name],[Shift] order by[Shift]) rn
from PunchCards
)
select *
from cte t1
left join cte t2
   on t1.[Name]=t2.[Name] and t1.rn=t2.rn
    and (
       (t1.[Shift]='Start Day Shift' and t2.[Shift]='End Day Shift')
     or(t1.[Shift]='Start Night Shift' and t2.[Shift]='End Night Shift')
     or(t2.[Shift]='Start Day Shift' and t1.[Shift]='End Day Shift')
     or(t2.[Shift]='Start Night Shift' and t1.[Shift]='End Night Shift')
  )
```

result is

| Name | Shift | rn | Name | Shift | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doug | Start Day Shift | 1 | null | null | null |
| John | End Day Shift | 1 | John | Start Day Shift | 1 |
| John | Start Day Shift | 1 | John | End Day Shift | 1 |
| Kate | End Night Shift | 1 | Kate | Start Night Shift | 1 |
| Kate | End Night Shift | 2 | null | null | null |
| Kate | Start Night Shift | 1 | Kate | End Night Shift | 1 |
| Michael | End Day Shift | 1 | Michael | Start Day Shift | 1 |
| Michael | Start Day Shift | 1 | Michael | End Day Shift | 1 |
| Paul | End Day Shift | 1 | Paul | Start Day Shift | 1 |
| Paul | End Night Shift | 1 | null | null | null |
| Paul | Start Day Shift | 1 | Paul | End Day Shift | 1 |
| Paul | Start Day Shift | 2 | null | null | null |